# Is "dispreferred" a mainstream word in English?

Tags: word-usage, negation, prefixes, past-participles

I just recently came across the word *dispreferred* in a linguistic document.  I have never heard the word used before, rather I generally hear something like "preferred something else" in everyday conversation.  Is *dispreferred* a linguistics/language specific term or does it have more widespread usage in non-technical conversations?  As I type the word *dispreferred*, I see a red underline indicating that I have entered a misspelled word.

Comment: I've also never heard it before. My advice, if you can avoid using it, by all means do.

Comment: The simple answer seems to be no it isn't. It's not in OED (Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: Google Books shows that *Dispreferred* arose around 1975 and has been almost entirely a linguistics term except for a brief vogue in economics, sociology and public-policy studies in the 70s and 80s.

Comment: I prefer _dispreferred_ to [_unpreferred_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unpreferred).

Comment: Why invent ugly new words when there is adequate vocabulary available? I would say "less favoured" ["less favored" if I were in the USA] or "not preferred" rather than "dispreferred". Not preferring is not the opposite of preferring, but rather the absence of preferring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not in my Merriam-Webster or dictionary.reference.com, and I've never heard of it.

[LanguageLog](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2186) has some citations for it, but the article seems to confirm, if anything, that it's linguists' jargon.

Answer (score 1):

'Mainstream', **No**. 'Word', **Yes**.

It's more of a domain-specific term defined in linguistics, although it does seem to appear in general English writing in a few instances. [*Of course some people will love (or hate) the heightened suspense or the "gambling thrill," more of which is possible in the multistage lottery, and will prefer (or dis- prefer) it to a simple lottery.*]<sup>[a](http://books.google.com/books?id=Eo6LhcFb2lMC&pg=PA263&dq=disprefer%20-dislike%20-linguistics%20-grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5j_dUMu_M8zIrQfE44GoAw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBDgK)</sup>

It also seems to appear in linguistics literature in its general English sense apart from reference by its DSL-definition. [*If "preferred'V'dispreferred" refer not to tastes/desires of the participants but to the sequential practices and ... And how do these different practices for preferred and dispreferred responses help us understand an important aggregate*]  <sup>[[b]](http://books.google.com/books?id=5XbJRFQ4dhsC&pg=PA63&dq=dispreferred%20-dislike%20-linguistics%20-grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lkDdUN_AA5DjrAfOx4GQDw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA)</sup>

See definition and some discussion on *disprefer* on Wiktionary:
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disprefer
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:disprefer

Answer (score 0):

In the academic field of Conversation Analysis (CA) this is a specific term for describing a type of statement or turn in a conversation. If, as you describe, this is a document in the field of linguistics then *dispreferred* may be the only accurate word to use.