# Non-negative opposite of "to prefer"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

What is the antonym of "to prefer" that does not sound too negative? Merriam-Webster lists several antonyms for ["to prefer"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/prefer), but all of them sound a bit too negative to me.

In a situation with many choices, I want to convey a preference towards a specific choice without putting the other choice(s) in a bad light. A long-winded way of writing this down is:

> I strongly prefer X over Y (but if X is unavailable, then I am perfectly fine with Y).
>   X is strongly preferred over Y (but if X is unavailable, then Y is also fine).

["disprefer"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disprefer) closely matches what I'm looking for, but it seems [not](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk%3adisprefer) to be a "real" word, so I'm not sure whether "Y is dispreferred over X" can be used in a scientific article.

Comment: You are looking more for a synonym, I guess!!

Comment: _disprefer_ is a real word but not common.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95733/is-dispreferred-a-mainstream-word-in-english

Comment: I **love** X but love Y in a different way...

Comment: Why would you strongly prefer something, then say the other is just as good too?  Your thought needs help.

Comment: Using a prefacing clause would also be a viable alternative: "While either X or Y are sufficient (both X and Y will yield quality results), X is preferable to Y." You could also say "Y is an acceptable substitute for X and will yield quality results."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preamble on the logical implication of an antonym

You are trying to confuse people's understanding of the term *antonym*.

Logically, speaking, the term you could have used is *antithesis*. However, since all the dictionaries define *antithesis* as *exact/direct* opposite, you should use the mathematically more precise term of *[null-hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_hypothesis)*

The antonym of *good* = *bad*
The null-hypothesis of *good* = *not good* <= {*bad*, *not bad but not good*}

For the hypothesis
John = good person

then the null-hypothesis of the correlation is
John = anything but good.

In English, it is very frequent for an antonym not being the exact null-hypothesis. In fact, it is frequently true that almost all natural languages have antonyms not being the null-hypothesis. This is due to the absence of a pure binary set of possible states in such cases.

If a phenomenon Z has the possible states sorted by intensity {a, b, c, d}, then we can be sure that

antonym of a = d

But, the null-hypothesis of a = not a = {b, c, d}

What is more difficult when the states of a phenomenon is unsortable or unrankable, then any state within such a phenomenon does not have a generally acceptable antonym.

#### Therefore, the antonym

Therefore the antonym of the word *prefer* is indeed among words describing its extreme opposite

- disapprove, disfavour, dislike.

You are asking for the null-hypothesis of *prefer*, and as I have anecdotally stated, the null-hypothesis of many words is not the generally accepted antonym, due to having non-binary repertoire of states. Prefer is one of those words.

Answer (score 1):

***disfavor*** (AmE) or ***[disfavour](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disfavour)*** (BrE) might fit also.

> *(tr)* to regard or treat with disapproval or dislike

Answer (score 1):

Consider the idiomatic "settle for" and "make do with."

> I strongly prefer X over Y (but if X is unavailable, then I will *settle for* Y).
>   X is strongly preferred over Y (but if X is unavailable, then I'll *settle for* Y).
>
> I strongly prefer X over Y (but if X is unavailable, then I will *make do with* Y).
>   X is strongly preferred over Y (but if X is unavailable, then I'll *make do with* Y).
>
> [settle for](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/settle+for): to accept in spite of incomplete satisfaction.
>
> [make do with](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/make+do+with.html): accept something less satisfactory because there's no alternative.

- Alternately, how about any of the following?

> I strongly prefer X over Y (but if X is unavailable, then  *Y will perfectly fit the brief*).
>
> X is strongly preferred over Y (but if X is unavailable, then *Y will perfectly fit (or serve) the purpose*).
>
> I strongly prefer X over Y (but if X is unavailable, then I will *be perfectly content with Y*).

Answer (score 0):

Object? I prefer going by train. I object to going by car due to the air pollution.

Other synonyms of the verb object are below:

verb:

people attending the meeting objected to nearly every element of the new ordinance: protest (against), lodge a protest against, **oppose**, raise objections to, express **disapproval** of, **take exception to**, **take issue with,** take a stand against, argue against, quarrel with, condemn, draw the line at, demur at, disapprove of, mind, complain about, cavil at, quibble about; beg to differ with; informal kick up a fuss/stink about, kvetch about. ANTONYMS approve, accept.

Comment: Objecting to something implies that there is something wrong/imperfect about the object. I'm looking for a word that does *not* convey this negative interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand wanting to put them in a bad light but not being negative, but following the examples you have given:

> X is strongly preferred, but Y is *tolerated*

Answer (score 0):

A single word to convey your sense eludes me, but I would use phrasing like, "My first choice, by far, is X; while my second--and still quite acceptable-- choice is Y." Or, "Between two good alternatives X and Y, I much prefer X."

Answer (score 0):

disinclined to Y.  Disinclined implies mild disapproval or hesitation.

Answer (score 0):

- Y is *second best* (or *third best*, or whatever is appropriate for the number of Xs that are preferable to Y).
- Y is *least good* (implying that it is somewhat good, rather than bad).

  - I recall reading *least best* once, but that's obviously ungrammatical,
    and I don't believe that it's an idiom,
    so it was either a typo or the product of a very bad writer.
- Y is *minimally acceptable* or *marginally acceptable*.

  - It might be possible to combine one of the other answers with *marginal*.

Answer (score -1):

In order of preference, X is a strong first if it’s still available; otherwise Y would be fine.

:)

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE! Please use the Post Your Answer button only for actual answers, as Stack Exchange is not a traditional forum but instead a Q/A platform. The question asks how to refer to Y rather than X, and in a scientific article.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Um, what? This is not a great answer, but it is an answer. What's this about a scientific article?

Comment: @Scott Last sentence of the question. Perhaps the comment could have been adjusted a bit more.