# Opposite of prefer?

Tags: single-word-requests

Should be synonymous with "not like it as much."

E.g.

> Do you prefer my alternative or ______ it?

Comment: Would you prefer my alternative  or not?

Comment: @user159691 I'd like it to be an option of "no your alternative is worse" rather than "not prefer"

Comment: If only it were _postfer_.

Comment: I would come up with "reject" or "discard".

Comment: Would you prefer my alternative or do you dislike it?

Comment: Would you please you explain to us [why the closest antonyms to prefer provided by a thesaurus are insufficient?](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/prefer?s=t)?

Comment: Related: [Is “dispreferred” a mainstream word in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95733)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-negative opposite of "to prefer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171993/non-negative-opposite-of-to-prefer)

Answer (score 2):

Consider *disdain* as the 'opposite' of prefer:

> **disdain** *verb*
>   Consider to be unworthy of one's consideration.
>   ‘By 1980, major record companies disdained the music, preferring the slicker stylings of the new wave.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disdain)

Note the contrast between *disdain* and *prefer* in the selected example above. *Disdain* is arguably stronger as a negative term than *prefer* as a positive term, but it's also weaker than *discard*. It parallels *prefer* as a description of someone's attitude, as opposed to their action.

Your example sentence would be:

- Would you prefer my alternative or disdain it?

Note, however, that "Would you prefer X?" is often taken to contrast X with some sort of an equivalent for X. In that sense, the contrast isn't between a positive and a negative opinion about X. I think this arises from the nature of the word *prefer*. For example, "Would you prefer my soup?" implies an alternative such as *my roast* or *her soup*.

Note also that strictly-speaking, the word *disdain* doesn't take two 'arguments' for a comparison. In the dictionary's example, *disdain* applies to just "the music", whereas *preferring* has both "the music" and "the ... stylings" in view. Had the example been "... preferred the music, disdaining the ... stylings ...", *preferred* would still have had both in view, while *disdaining* would only apply to the "stylings". If you simply wish to compare two alternatives (say, yours and *his*), you can say the following without using an antonym to *prefer*:

- Would you prefer my alternative *to his*?

Comment: +1 I prefer "reject" but do not distain "distain".

Comment: @ab2 Thank you :) . I'd reject *reject* since a preference isn't an acceptance.  I've added to my answer; neither of the answers so far has proposed an antonym with the ditransitivity of *prefer*.

Answer (score 1):

Would **dislike** work? Or do you **disfavor** such a trivial answer? :p

Comment: dislike doesn't work at all. Disfavor at first sounded like it would work but apparently it means something else: "put at a disadvantage or treat as undesirable"